# Change many imageView sources using for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, imageview

I have 100 imageview in my layout :

```
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
    ...
    ...
    iv98 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView98);
    iv99 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView99);
    iv100 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView100);
```

Now, in my program I want change all image sources time to time, so now how i do this i want some thing like this

```
for (int F=1; F<101; i++) {
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("a"+F, "drawable", getPackageName());
    ivF.setImageResource(resID); 
}
```

so, any suggestion ?

thanks.

Comment: 100 imageview's in one layout? why do you need so many?

Comment: @Raghunandan Some apps icons.

Comment: why don't you use lazy loading with listview?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like your biggest issue is your design / implementation. 100 ImageViews in one layout is crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by my own, this how I should declare ImageView

```
ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4,iv5,iv6;
ImageView[] image = {iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4,iv5,iv6}
```

and then when i need to set an image :

```
for (int F=1; F<7; F++) {

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("a"+F, "drawable", getPackageName());
image[F].setImageResource(resID); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create it dynamically , set ids to them and use these ids as per your need to get image references .